# Integral with a limit; integral and inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following problem.
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \int_0^h\frac{\sqrt{t^2+9}}{h}\mathrm{d}t
$$

My presumption is that I should just evaluate the function at $0$, but I can't justify why the answer is $3$ and where the $h$ goes. How does this work?

---

Also, I am asked to prove that $\sin{x} \le x$ in the interval $(0,1)$. Then I need to justify why the following is true.

$$
\int_0^1(\sin{x})^{2012} \le \frac{1}{2013}
$$

---

I'm sorry about the trouble. I haven't seen exercises like these two before and I am unsure of how I am supposed to solve them.

---

For the first one, I should have placed it in a form where it may be seen as a derivative.

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_0^h\sqrt{t^2+9}\space \mathrm{d}t - \int_0^0\sqrt{t^2+9}\space \mathrm{d}t}{h}
$$

Where, as André suggested, we define

$$
F(x) = \int_0^x\sqrt{9+t^2}\mathrm{d}t
$$

So it basically is

$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(0+h)-F(0)}{h} = F'(0) = \sqrt{0^2+9}=3
$$

---

This is my attempt at the second problem. Is it right?

$$
\sin{x}\le x \\
(\sin{x})^{2012} \le x^{2012} \\
\int_0^1(\sin{x})^{2012} \le \int_0^1x^{2012} \\
\int_0^1(\sin{x})^{2012} \le \int_0^1x^{2012} = \frac{x^{2013}}{2013}\bigg|_0^1=\frac{1}{2013}
$$

Comment: For the inequality, show that $|\sin(t)| \leq |t|$ using the mean value theorem.

Comment: Alternatively, use the Taylor expansion for $\sin x$ to see that $\sin x \leq x$ in $(0, 1)$. For the second question, use the fact that $\sin x \leq x$ in $(0, 1)$ to conclude $(\sin x)^{2012} \leq x^{2012}$ in $(0, 1)$, and use that to conclude $\int_{0}^{1} (\sin x)^{2012}dx \leq \int_{0}^{1} x^{2012}dx$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do the first question is to let
$$F(x)=\int_0^x \sqrt{t^2+9}\,dt.$$
Then our limit, *by definition*, is $F'(0)$. Evaluate $F'(0)$ using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

In my opinion a better way goes as follows. For simplicity, suppose that $h\gt 0$. Then 
$$h\sqrt{0+9}\lt \int_0^h \sqrt{t^2+9}\,dt \lt h\sqrt{h^2+9}.$$
Divide through by $h$, and Squeeze. (Negative $h$ can be dealt with similarly, the inequalities reverse.)

Comment: So (I think I'm *supposed* to use the first solution) I should do something to turn the expression into something that becomes a derivative, to then apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: The expression **is** a derivative. Define $F(x)$ as I did. Then $F(0)=0$. So we are asked to find $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(0+h)-F(0)}{h}$. By definition, this is $F'(0)$.

Comment: Just a small last question. The "intermediate" step in that reasoning is that $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(h)}{h}$ has an integral above and the $h$ below may be taken inside, hence turning it into the original expression?

Comment: The expression $\frac{F(0+h)-F(0)}{h}$ is **exactly** the same as the given expression, since $F(0)=0$. No intermediate step.

Comment: But if $F(h)=\int_0^h f(t)dt$, the $h$ of the denominator doesn't appear right away, does it? That's what I meant. i.e. $\frac{\int_0^h f(t)dt}{h}$.  I ask because I am pretty much new to integrals formally.

Comment: The expression you were given is $\int_0^h \frac{f(t)}{h}\,dt$. With my definition of $F$, this is exactly $\frac{F(0+h)}{h}$. This is exactly $\frac{F(0+h)-F(0)}{h}$. The limit as $h$ goes to $0$ is therefore by definition exactly $F'(0)$. Calculate $F'(0)$ using FTC.

Comment: Oh, I see your problem, maybe. For the integration, $h$ is a constant. Recall that $\int_a^b kg(t)\,dt=k\int_a^b g(t)\,dt$.

Comment: I see. I didn't know exactly how to treat the $h$. Thanks. $h$ here, $t$ there, $x$ too. I got messed up.

Comment: You are perhaps expected to use FTC. But do look at the second solution. It comes to grips concretely with the size of $\int_0^h \frac{f(t)}{h}\,dt$.

Comment: Now that I see how to move the $h$, it is clearly more intuitive and, well, simpler. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that,

> $$ \lim_{h \to 0} \int_0^h\frac{\sqrt{t^2+9}}{h}\mathrm{d}t = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(h)}{h} .$$

Now, you can use L'hopital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:**
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \int_0^h\frac{\sqrt{t^2+9}}{h}\mathrm{d}t=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_0^h\sqrt{t^2+9}\mathrm{d}t}{h}$$
This is of the form $\frac00$ so you can apply L'Hôpital's rule.

**Hint 2:** Notice that $\sin0=0$ and that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin x=\cos x \le1=\frac{d}{dx}x$$
**Hint 3:** Use ***Hint 2*** to show that
$$\int_0^1(\sin{x})^{2012}dx \le\int_0^1x^{2012} dx$$